# Why the node's label affect the query performance significantly in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I try to simplify my question. If all nodes in Neo4jDB have same label `Science`, what's the difference between `MATCH n WHERE n.ID="UUID-0001" RETURN n` and `MATCH (n:Science) WHERE n.ID="UUID-0001" RETURN n`. Why the performance is not the same?

My Neo4j database contains about 70000 nodes and 100 relations.

The nodes have two types: `Paper` and `Author`, and they both have an `ID` field.

I created each node with corresponding label, and I also use `ID` as the index.

However, since one of my functions need to query nodes by ID without considering the label. The query just like: `MATCH n WHERE n.ID="UUID-0001" RETURN n`. The query time cost about `4000~5000 ms`!

But after adding `Science` for each node and using `MATCH (n:Science) WHERE n.ID="UUID-0001" RETURN n`. The query time became about 1000~1100 ms. Does anyone know the difference between these two cases?

*PS. Count(n:Science) = Count(n:Paper) + Count(n:Author), which mean each node has two labels.*

Comment: Always use a single label and single property that is indexed for the lookup by property value.

Comment: create an index: `create index on :Science(ID);`

Comment: the query time is faster because it doesn't has to scan the whole db anymore but just the nodes with the label :Science

Comment: But in my case, Since there are two types of node in DB, and I also create `:Paper(ID)` and `:Author(ID)`. The performance is good when I want to query specific type. However, I have a function cross two types of node, so I have to use `MATCH n .... RETURN n` but the performance is bad. Then I add new label `:Science` to each node and use `MATCH (n:Science) .... RETURN n`, the performance become better. But why? Since every nodes have `Science` label, the query time should be same in these cases.

Comment: @Michael Hunger, Please give me some advise if you have time, many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Because for every label Neo4j automatically creates an extra index. The Cypher language can be broadly thought of as piping + filtering, so Match n WHere ... will first get *every node* and then filter on the where part. Whereas Match (n:Science) Where... will get every node with label science (using an index) and then try to match the where. From your query performance we can see that about 1/5th of your nodes were marked science so the query runs in a fifth he time, because it did a fifth as many comparisons.

Comment: In addition to this, the index declared on `ID` is only used when a label is invoked. `MATCH n WHERE n.ID="UUID-0001" RETURN n` happens entirely in Cypher.

Comment: Its always been unclear to me how the indexes on properties work. If it were a hash map linking to the node, then it should give O(1) retrieval when invoked, but they don't.

Comment: But in my situation, the number of nodes marked as `Science` is equal to the summation of `Paper` and `Author`, I don't know why the performance are different. Thanks :)

Comment: @phil the indexes on label + property use an tree based index with O(log(n)) lookup.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense if you want to use the index for > or < type comparisons too, as you can put numbers in a BST or something. So your saying the problem here is that he created two indexes :Paper(ID) and :Author(ID) and Cypher doesn't see them as being one index, so it doesn't invoke either of them? 

One second still seems really slow for an indexed look up.

Comment: @phil_20686, yes, when I use `MATCH n ...`, I don't see the result as being indexed. I have to add another `:Science` label, and it seems to use index for the query.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I got the advisement from @phil_20686 and @Michael Hunger, but I think these answers do not solve my question.

I think there are some tricks when using label. If their are 10 thousand nodes in Neo4j DB, and the type of these nodes are the same. The query will perform better when adding label to these nodes.

I hope this post can help some people and give me some feedback if you find the reasons. Thanks.